# ionic 4 menu don't work on android mobile app but works on desktop

Tags: android, angular, ionic4, ionic-cli

Menu works fine on desktop, But when I build an app and run on android menu do not work, It don't even shows menu toggle button in app .

App Component :

```html
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane contentId="main-content">
    <ion-menu contentId="main-content" type="overlay">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages">
            <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>
                {{p.title}}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="main-content" class="splash"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

List Component :

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      List
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      <ion-icon [name]="item.icon" slot="start"></ion-icon>
      {{item.title}}
      <div class="item-note" slot="end">
        {{item.note}}
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

ionic frameword : 4.11 
ionic cli: 5.4.13 
angular: 8 
android: 7

Comment: You can please share your apk file?

Comment: if you remove ion split pane what happens? also can you share css for class “splash”? it’s on your router outlet which you are not supposed to style